# Get wifi and ethernet from ethernet socket

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

I have a weak wifi signal in a room but I have an ethernet wall socket. I have it connected to a computer and I want to know if I can get wifi signal from that ethernet socket and still have an ethernet output for the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put in a small Wireless router, connect it to your home system.

1. Connect a LAN port on the router to your Ethernet wall socket.
2. Give the router a Static IP address on your network (outside of the DHCP address scope) so that the router can withstand restarts and stay connected.
3. Turn DHCP OFF on the small router.
4. Set up secure Wireless

Now you have both Ethernet and Wireless in this area.

Comment: It seems obvious but it's definitely worth mentioning that the *LAN* ports on this additional router would provide the additional Ethernet connections. If this isn't specified, some people reading this won't be 100% sure and will use the *WAN* port by mistake. It's almost 50/50 which one non-technical people will go for! When you're explaining the basics to people, it's best to assume no prior knowledge, rather than assuming some. I see people get stuck on little details like this all the time, where it was deemed "too obvious" to include something in instructions the first time around! 